# evaluate the limit of $\frac {x}{|x|^s}$ as $s<1$ and $x$ goes to $0$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, normed-spaces

Evaluate $lim_{x\to 0} \frac {x}{|x|^s}$ for $s<1$ and $x\in \mathbb R^n$. For $n = 1$, I think this limit is equal to $0$. However I am trying to evaluate it when $x$ is an vector in arbitrary dimension. Does this limit exist?

Comment: It is not proper to edit a question  after answers have appeared.

Comment: answers were posted during editing. Sry.

Comment: There is hardly any difference between the cases $s=\frac 1 2$ and $0 <s<1$.

Comment: yeah, I think your post is right as well. I didn't vote down your post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** $\displaystyle\left\|\frac x{\sqrt{\|x\|}}\right\|=\sqrt{\|x\|}$.

Comment: A very powerful hint.

Comment: My answer is same as this except that I used  $|x|$ for the norm. What kind of voting is going on here?

Comment: So, by definition, norm of a vector is 0 if and only if this vector is 0. Hence this limit is 0 vector. Right?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Sometimes, the voting is so random.

Comment: The limit is $0$ because $\lim_{x\to0}\sqrt{\|x\|\|}=\sqrt{\lim_{x\to0}\|x\|}=\sqrt0=0$.